# What is the correct fallback if content negotiation fails?

Tags: rest, content-negotiation

What is the correct fallback if Content-Negotiation does not find a reasonable result due to a non 2xx status code? For example:

A client wants to download a PDF and sends following header `Accept: application/pdf`. Due to insufficient privileges the server would return a `403 Forbidden`. You might want to explain the reason in more detail but it does not make much sense to return a PDF. How would you deal with that?

Should the server return an empty body? Should he ignore the `Accept` header and send some other representation like `text/plain`. Or is it the job of the client to provide alternatives per `Accept: application/pdf, text/plain, */*`.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously if the user does not have permission to access the resource, there is no real alternative what a server can do. The server can however respond with content (even in an error case) which describes the error in more detail, if that response can be made using a `media-type` accepted by the client. The client should provide an `Accept:` header that describes all the `media-type`s it can parse. So an automatic client would be able to do:

```
Accept: application/pdf, application/vnd.myapi.error
```

If content-negotiation fails, the returned code should be `406 Not Acceptable`. The server can produce this if it can not provide any answer which would be acceptable to the client.

However, the specification states that the server *may* actually return an answer not explicitly acceptable by the client if it wants to, it is up to the client, to inspect the response headers to see what `media-type` the answer is.

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4.1

Comment: Transforming every 4xx to 406 if content negotiation fails seems odd. Especially because you can't return the list of supported media types in this case.

I'd favor returning a sane format (like JSON) if it's along the spec.

Comment: Well, according to my reading the server can basically ignore the `Accept` header if it wants to, so you should be ok. Note that permission problems should be still `403`, that is not a content negotiation problem.

Comment: 403 is just an example. You also return a nice web page if Content-Type is text/html and the status is 404. Or you would explain what the client did wrong in case of a 400. But I never saw someone sending a PDF in this case. Maybe the title of the question is a bit missleading.

Comment: Note that RFC 2626 was replaced and your cite was removed in [RFC 7231](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.6). If I understand this correctly it would make sense to return a 406 and a list of supported Media Types. But I can hardly imagine a client who would do a second request for a 404 just to get a better representation?

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the link, I updated my reference where it describes that the server *can* send a default message. Whether it should just send a standard `text/html` body or not: I worked (as a client) with an API that would return json-formatted "hints" as to what went wrong. I found it really helpful. It contained things like: "You can't, but you could if you try with amount > 50".